# How to develop a WCF Service to automatically manage other related WCF services hosted as Window Service?

Tags: wcf

Kindly help me in architecting a solution which is required for my ongoing project.
I have developed some WCF Services hosted as windows services which I did and working fine so far. Now I am asked to develop a master WCF type of service which should be intelligent enough to manage all other WCF service for possible corruption/errors and can repair them and restart.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we have written a custom host and took us years to make it a real application server, I will share some of the challenges that we had. Creating a custom host that manages WCF services as an NT service is a very challenging task if you want to manage all of the details and treat the NT service as a real service host. The challenges start from managing multiple Appdomains ( one for each Service ), managing the statuses of the services, startup times, deployments from the IDE and the worst of all is activation. Have you considered how to implement that? If you do not have this feature, it means that all of your services will be active and in memory at all times. IIS and Appfabric do that very well and trust me , it is noty easy to implement. The other part that was challenging was a UI to manage this host and offcourse a UI that can manage multiple hosts ( NT services running on different boxes ). Do you need a discovery proxy implementation? And at last how about if you want to manage services running in your custom host , IIS and App fabric the same way?
Think about before doing such an implementation because the scope may crypt on you as you do it.

Comment: Thanks buddy... We finally got rid from this requirement as project got scrapped due to bad architectural decisions by our technical person. I also investigated a lot and I agree that it is one of most complex requirement and also it make very little sense.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar here.

- Create a `Dictionary<key, ApplicationDomain>` collection into your main program

  - `Key`: something unique for each application domain, like a `Guid` or a `System.Type`.
- That `ApplicationDomain` class exposes a internal property to access your `AppDomain` proxy (that which inherits a `MarshallByRef` class)
- Load your WCF host into main program, so you'll get access to that collection
- Every time your service get some access, you just need to take that key, access your proxy and do anything you want within your service hoster.

Keypoint: Your service must have access to all your service hosts.